# Suppress warning when using fakeslant instead of italic for small caps

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I have one small need to use italic small caps, and my font lacks them. So I'm using fakeslant. The code below works with lualatex, but I get this warning message:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/SourceSerifPro(0)/m/scit' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/SourceSerifPro(0)/m/scsl' instead on input line 1
```

Is there something I can do to suppress the warning?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont
  [ UprightFont     = *-Regular ,
    ItalicFont      = *-Italic ,
    BoldFont        = *-Semibold ,
    BoldItalicFont  = *-SemiboldIt ,
    SlantedFont     = SourceSerifPro-Regular,
    SlantedFeatures = {FakeSlant=0.2},
  ]
  {Source Serif Pro}
\begin{document}
\emph{\textsc{Hello}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Simplest way  is to use `\textsl` instead of `\textit`. You could also declare `ItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont=.., SmallCapsFeatures=...}`.

Comment: I don't think I can use `\textsl`, since the italics are added by the genealogy package in my actual document. What would I put for `..` if I used `ItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont=..}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ignore the warning, which is harmless, or use `\textsl` and `\slshape` instead of `\textit` and `\itshape`.  Or you can set up the slanted small caps font as your italic small caps font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont
  [ UprightFont     = *-Regular ,
    ItalicFont      = *-Italic ,
    BoldFont        = *-Semibold ,
    BoldItalicFont  = *-SemiboldIt ,
    SlantedFont     = SourceSerifPro-Regular,
    SlantedFeatures = {FakeSlant=0.2},
    ItalicFeatures  = { SmallCapsFont = SourceSerifPro-Regular,
                        SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps, FakeSlant=0.2} }
  ]
  {Source Serif Pro}
\begin{document}
\emph{\textsc{Hello}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Source Serif Pro sample]